# Number of matrices over finite fields $\mathbb{F}_q$ with some minors to be $0$ is (or is not?) polynomial in $q$?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

It's well-known that
$$\# \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q)=(q^2-1)(q^2-q)$$
is a ($\mathbb{Z}$-coefficient) polynomial of $q$. As a corollary,
$$\#\left\{ A \in M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{F}_q)\, \middle|\,\det A =0 \right\}=q^4-(q^2-1)(q^2-q)$$
is a polynomial of $q$.

In general, fix $n \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$, $\Lambda$ denotes for the subset of
$$X:=\left\{ (k,I,J)\, \middle|\, \begin{aligned}
   &I:1 \leqslant i_1 < \cdots <i_k \leqslant m\\
   &J:1 \leqslant j_1 < \cdots <j_k \leqslant m
   \end{aligned}  \right\},$$
$A_{I,J}$ denote for the corresponding minor, is
$$\#\left\{ A \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{F}_q)\, \middle|\,A_{I,J} =0, \;\forall\, (k,I,J) \in \Lambda  \right\}$$
always a polynomial of $q$?

A possible nontrivial case to work with:
$$\#\left\{ A \in M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb{F}_q)\, \middle|\,\begin{vmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12}  \\ a_{21} & a_{22}  \end{vmatrix} =\begin{vmatrix} a_{22} & a_{23} \\ a_{32} & a_{33}  \end{vmatrix} =\begin{vmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}  \end{vmatrix}=0 \right\}.$$

When the answer is true, maybe the proof can be generalized to show that
$$\#\left\{ A \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{F}_q)\, \middle|\,\begin{aligned}
   &A_{I_1,J_1} =0, \;\forall\, (k,I_1,J_1) \in \Lambda_1\\
   &A_{I_2,J_2} =1, \;\forall\, (k,I_2,J_2) \in \Lambda_2\\
    &A_{I_3,J_3} \neq 0, \;\forall\, (k,I_3,J_3) \in \Lambda_3
   \end{aligned}  \right\} \qquad (\ast)$$
is a polynomial of $q$, where $\Lambda_1, \Lambda_2,\Lambda_3$ are disjoint subsets of $X$. When the answer is false, the counterexample should be not too complicated. Anyhow, this can be viewed as a purely combinational problem.

Related question: [Number of $3\times 3$ anticommuting matrices over finite fields $\mathbb{F}_p$ is (or is not?) polynomial in $p$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/404817/number-of-3-times-3-anticommuting-matrices-over-finite-fields-mathbbf-p-i)

Edit: at least for the generalization $(\ast)$, there is a counterexample. The number
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\#\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} a & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & b & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & c  \end{pmatrix} \in M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb{F}_q)\, \middle|\,\begin{vmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & b  \end{vmatrix} =\begin{vmatrix} b & 0 \\ 0 & c  \end{vmatrix} =\begin{vmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & c  \end{vmatrix}=1 \right\}\\
=\;& \#\left\{ a \in \mathbb{F}_q^{\times}\, \middle|\,a^2=1 \right\}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
is **not** a polynomial of $q$.